# Get an exception when loading Android Layout XML file

Tags: android

For some reason I get the following exception when I load the XML layout in eclipse.

I am not too sure what might be causing this as I don't believe I have made any new changes to the file. Also when I render the layout with `API 19` in eclipse, there is no exception. However, when I render with API 21, I get the below exception? What might trigger this sort of exception?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawShadow(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:74)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:61)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15223)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:592)
at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1689)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15022)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15017)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15022)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3404)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15117)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:587)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:334)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:517)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1584)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1066)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:686)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:294)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1085)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1070)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:782)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:3110)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1794)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:283)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4353)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1061)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4172)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3761)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: The Eclipse IDE preview is having some problem with the layout file. There is unlikely to be a lot that you can do about it, other than to try it in Android Studio and see if you get better results. You're welcome to post the layout file here, in case somebody sees something in it that might explain your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I did not post the XML layout as it is for my assignment, just wanted a point in the right direction. I will take a look at using Android Studio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue in Android Studio. In my case, the root layout was a LinearLayout. In there, I had a nested RelativeLayout with the layout height and width as match_parent and a DrawerLayout included whose layout height and width was also match_parent. I also had a Button and TextView in the RelativeLayout. I think AndroidStudio couldn't draw the Button and/or TextView because of all the nested 'match_parent's.

I would try looking at the nested layouts. If your issue isn't the nested layouts, I would try altering your layout little by little to see what the IDE isn't able to render.